# Three.js moving sprites to vertices (positions) of cone or any other geometry

Tags: animation, three.js, sprite

At this moment I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/19/) working. I tryed many things. I tryed to get vertices positions from a geometry like in [this example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html), but `geometry.computeCentroids();` doesn't work in new three.js and now im having trouble with getting my sprites to vertices positions of a random geometry.

How can I make sprites morph into a other geometry? I want to know how to make sprites move to vertices positions of other geometry, lika a cone or OBJ model. Thanks in advance for all the help!

```
var camera, scene, renderer,controls;

var particlesTotal = 512,
    positions = [],
    objects = [],
    current = 0;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
    camera.position.set( 600, 400, 1500 );
    camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3() );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();



    var material=new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        //map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprite.png'),
        color:0xffffff
    });

    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
        var object = new THREE.Sprite(material);
       // object.scale.x = 0.1;
       // object.scale.y = 0.1;
        object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
            object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
            object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000
        scene.add( object );
        objects.push( object );

    }


        transition();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function transition() {


    // Plane
    var amountX = 16;
    var amountZ = 32;
    var separation = 150;
    var offsetX = ( ( amountX - 1 ) * separation ) / 2;
    var offsetZ = ( ( amountZ - 1 ) * separation ) / 2;
    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
        var x = ( i % amountX ) * separation;
        var z = Math.floor( i / amountX ) * separation;
        var y = ( Math.sin( x * 0.5 ) + Math.sin( z * 0.5 ) ) * 200;
        positions.push( x - offsetX, y, z - offsetZ );
    }

    // Cube
    var amount = 8;
    var separation = 150;
    var offset = ( ( amount - 1 ) * separation ) / 2;
    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
        var x = ( i % amount ) * separation;
        var y = Math.floor( ( i / amount ) % amount ) * separation;
        var z = Math.floor( i / ( amount * amount ) ) * separation;
        positions.push( x - offset, y - offset, z - offset );
    }

    // Random
    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
        positions.push(
            Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
            Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
            Math.random() * 4000 - 2000
        );
    }

    // Sphere
    var radius = 750;
    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
        var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / particlesTotal );
        var theta = Math.sqrt( particlesTotal * Math.PI ) * phi;
        positions.push(
            radius * Math.cos( theta ) * Math.sin( phi ),
            radius * Math.sin( theta ) * Math.sin( phi ),
            radius * Math.cos( phi )
        );
    }

    var offset = current * particlesTotal * 3;
    var duration = 2000;

    for ( var i = 0, j = offset; i < particlesTotal; i ++, j += 3 ) {
        var object = objects[ i ];
        new TWEEN.Tween( object.position )
            .to( {
            x: positions[ j ],
            y: positions[ j + 1 ],
            z: positions[ j + 2 ]
        }, Math.random() * duration + duration )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
            .start();
    }
    new TWEEN.Tween( this )
        .to( {}, duration * 3 )
        .onComplete( transition )
        .start();

    current = ( current + 1 ) % 4;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    TWEEN.update();
    controls.update();

    var time = performance.now();
    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
        var object = objects[ i ];
        var scale = Math.sin( ( Math.floor( object.position.x ) + time ) * 0.002 ) * 0.3 + 1;
        scale*=100;
        object.scale.set( scale, scale, scale );


    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
     renderer.autoClear = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not not hard but needs some maths homework. Here is the idea, writing the corresponding code should not be hard then ... :

In the example, for N particles, N positions are added to a `position` array. That is why 'special' formulas are written (instead `SphereGeometry` or `BoxGeometry`) because each time the particles move to an other shape, their positions are tweened to their i+N new value in the array, and it's not regular to create a geometry by asking it to have N vertices.

If you want to use a custom geometry, or an existing geometry class instead of finding other formulas yourself, the solution is to :

1. create the geometry
2. loop through its `geometry.vertices` array (let's call its length 'L')
3. and apply some maths : basically, only copy the position met each L/N vertices.

   ```
   for(var i=0;i<L;i+=L/N)position.push(geometry.vertices[i].clone());
   ```
4. However most of the time L/N will not result in an integer : it will have a remainder. So you need more maths. Let's use an example.

You have 50 particles so you need to push 50 new values in the `position` array, to design your new shape.

If this shape has 111 vertices you cannot copy each position, there are more than 50. You can easily imagine to copy only each 111 / 50 = 2.22 (so each 2) vertices. Problem, the remainder is 11 : when you arrive at 2 * 50 = 100, your shape will have a hole of 11 / 2 ~= 5 vertices, in this case it is 10% of the copied shape. So sometimes you have to copy not each 2 but each 3 vertices to get an average offset and a correct spread of your sprites over your shape. How many times ? 11 / 3 = 3.6666.. ~= 3 times. Those times also have to be spread in the loop not to occur one after the other : 50 / 3 ~= 17. The first time has to be at the 17/2 = 8 or 9 (you decide) action, to delete the general shift. We are done.

Conclusion, you have to write a loop that checks all vertices. It pushes the value in the `position` array every 2 vertices, until the 8th loop (so at the 16th position) where after the copy it jumps to the 16 + 3 = 19th position. It starts again every 2 values....

until the 19 + 17 * 2 = 53rd position where it jumps at the 56th....

same at the 56 + 17 * 2 = 90th position where it jumps at the 93rd....

That is it :)

Comment: I could make sprites start in a cone geometry, but the transition function is not working correctly. Can I quickly fix my code or do I need to use ur code to make it work? And is it hard to get sprites on faces of a geomtery? This is what I have now http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/40/.

Comment: I have read your answer, after I made that old code. I modifided your code 'position.push(geometry.vertices[i].clone());' and now I have sprites moving to other vertices (positions) (http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/55/). As you already said there would be holes, when there are going to be more vertices than sprites. If I use 'for(var i=0;i<L;i+=L/N)', then I will have to delete particlesTotal? I have everything working with 'particlesTotal', but can't make tetrahedron, because it probably only has four vertices. Is .clone() supposed to duplicate sprites and move them to positions that fill holes?

Comment: 1/ Don't use the 'for...' formula you quoted because of what is explained at 4. 2/ `N=particlesTotal`. 3/ If you have less than N vertices you have to find your own formulas, like the ones in the original example. 4/ Here `clone()` is applied to a `vector3` so it duplicates a `vector3`. Not sure you understand the code of the original example yet.

Comment: I could write a code to increase 'particlesTotal' when neccesary or it wouldn't work?

Comment: You need to study the logic of the original code, can't help you more. Also if an answer is helpful you can validate it or just upvote.

Comment: Yes, it helped to get me what I wanted, but how can I duplicate sprites when necessary to fill the holes?

Comment: Didn't I answered this question yet in the 4th paragraph ... ? Study the original code and make sure you understand it and this answer. Then in 10 minutes max you will be able to solve your issues.

Comment: After some trying I still couldn't get it to duplicate the sprites. This is the code I had `var objectl = cone2.geometry.vertices; | for ( var i = 0; i < objectl.length; i+=2 ) {...` I dont know where I need to put the code to duplicate the needed sprites. Can u maybe help me fix the error? I understand what you mean, but I can't write the right code. And how can I put sprites on faces? I would probably need to use 'geometry.faces[i].clone()' or it's more difficult? Any good example would be great for me.

Comment: You do not understand the original example. Sprites are not cloned, there is a `position` array where for N particles you push N `vector3`-s in. Re-read my answer : do not increase `i` by 2 because you will have holes in the resulting shape. Check all vertices (`i+=1` or `i++`) and only push them at the conditions written. I gave you the logic, translating it to javascript is not a hard task. If you cannot do it, consider also that people on stackoverflow can't write your projects for free. Try to re-write the original example without looking at it if you want to make sure you understand it.

Comment: Well your answer helped me to get what I want, so i'll just accept your answer. Thanks for all the help!